# Implement WebView in modal bottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to implement the modal bottom sheet with a webview as a child in it. When I try to do it, the webview gets messed up and the sheet comes on the top of the screen instead of the bottom.

I tried to change the height but nothing really worked.

```
Pub dependency: flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.5
```

```dart
  void _showModelSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return new Container(
            height: screenHeight / 4,
            child: new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.amber,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                      topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0))),
              child: Container(
                child: new MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  routes: {
                    "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
                          url: "https://www.google.com",
                        ),
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

```dart
child: RaisedButton(
                    elevation: 10,
                    splashColor: Colors.black,
                    color: Colors.red.shade900.withOpacity(0.7),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(110)),
                    onPressed: _showModelSheet,
                    child: Text(
                      "sheet"),
),
),
```

I want to make the whole webview to get wrap into the height of the modal bottom sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a `MaterialApp` inside another. And the reason is that the plugin you're using forces you to do that.

Better use the oficial Flutter WebView plugin.

```
webview_flutter: ^0.3.9+1
```

Then use it like this:

```
void _showModelSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (builder) {
        return new Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
          child: new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber, borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(topLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(20.0))),
            child: Container(
                child: WebView(
              initialUrl: 'https://google.com',
            )),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          elevation: 10,
          splashColor: Colors.black,
          color: Colors.red.shade900.withOpacity(0.7),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(110)),
          onPressed: _showModelSheet,
          child: Text("sheet"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, buddy, but I can't Scroll the page.

Comment: Your welcome, well that's the normal behaviour. Because the modalBottomSheet has a gesture support up and down. Therefore the scroll is not detected. I'll try to look at it later, and see if I can find a workaround to that. Here you have a closed issue with that matter, maybe it can help you. [https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/497](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/497)

Comment: By the way, do you want it to be a bottom sheet for a specific reason? Because if you don't need the pull down gesture, you could mimic a bottom sheet with an AnimatedContainer.

Comment: I mean, I just saw videos about modal bottom sheets, So I thought it'd be nice to build that and experiment with it. I didn't know about mimicing bottom sheet with the animated container.

Comment: `enableDrag = false` in `showModalBottomSheet` allows scrolling of the WebView.